# resx files - remove default file with no language

Tags: c#, internationalization, resx

I've got a App_GlobalResources folder with a different resource file per culture:

```
Resource.en-gb.resx
Resource.fr-fr.resx
.
.
Resource.resx
```

It looks like this last Resource.resx "default" file with no language associated with it has to exist there by design.

Is there a way to get rid of this last default file without breaking the code?

Comment: Simply you shouldn't remove it. ResourceMangager design code will be "linked" to it + the fallback mechanism relies on it. Resources.resx should contain English. But all common english texts to it and only the diffs to the en-GB, en-US etc. files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. Asp.Net uses the

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

to identify the present culture. It looks for resource file which has associated culture in the above property. If the associated file is not found then, it will fallback to the default language's resource. So make sure this file is part of your installer.

good luck...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can just delete it. But I would not. This is the default fallback language. So just copy your most likely used language into it.

Comment: ResourceManager will not work without the default resx file!